# Не меняется BackgroundImage у формы

Tags: c#, winforms

Задача такова: выбрать картинку из листбокса в одной форме, и при нажатии на кнопку поставить эту выбранную картинку на background другой формы.
При загрузке формы активирую метод по загрузке картинок в listbox:

```
private void SettingsProg_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ImageList(Application.StartupPath + "\\");          
}

string patch = @"D:\\Images";
private void ImageList(string aPath)
{
    DirectoryInfo directory = new DirectoryInfo(patch);
    FileInfo[] files = directory.GetFiles("*.*");
    listBox1.Items.Clear();

    foreach (FileInfo file in files)
    {
        if ((file.Extension == ".jpg" || file.Extension == ".png"))
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(file.Name);
            Images[count] = file.FullName.ToString();
            count++;
        }
    }
    adres = patch;
}
```

При нажатии на кнопку отправляю данные в другую форму:

```
private void setImage_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form2 form = new Form2();
    form.BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile(adres + "\\" + listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString());
    MessageBox.Show("Фон изменен.");
}
```

Когда изменяю таким образом фон той формы, на котором проходит действие - меняет, а на другой не меняет.
Подскажите, что я упустил?

Comment: В методе `setImage_Click` вы создаёте новый экземпляр `Form2`, присваиваете ему `background` но дальше этот экземпляр формы нигде не показываете. Я так понимаю - Вы хотите поменять `background` у уже существующего  и показанного экземпляра `Form2`?

Comment: Да. Мне ведь надо как-то передать данные в другую форму. Поэтому я и создал новый экземпляр, чтобы отправить background в ту форму.

Comment: У каждого экземпляра свой background, поэтому таким действием Вы не меняете background у уже отображенной формы. Чтобы поменять background у уже отображенной формы Вам нужно сохранить ссылку на её экземпляр так, чтобы она была доступна из формы где вы хотите менять background.

Comment: Понял. А показать как это примерно должно выглядеть, можете?

Comment: Вот модельный пример того, что я имел ввиду http://pastebin.com/m2P5KhTH Надеюсь это прояснит для Вас ситуацию :)

Comment: Прояснило. Однако, как я понял, это не то что нужно. Просто вторая форма она как бы главная. Ваш алгоритм будет каждый раз создавать новое окно,а это не надо.

Comment: В приведённом по ссылке примере и Form1 и Form2 создаются только один раз.  Каждый раз форма создаётся в Вашем примере как раз, только не отображается.

Answer (score 1):

Как правильно указал пользователь **ApInvent** при каждом нажатии кнопки `setImage` вы создаете новые экземпляры `Form2`. Для решения можно создать один глобальный экземпляр `Form2` и для него устанавливать фон:

```
string patch = @"D:\\Images";
public Form2 form = new Form2();

private void SettingsProg_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ImageList(Application.StartupPath + "\\");
    form.Show();          
}

private void ImageList(string aPath)
{
    ...
}

private void setImage_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    form.BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile(adres + "\\" + listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString());
    MessageBox.Show("Фон изменен.");
}
```

Таким образом вы создаете 1 раз глобальный экземпляр `Form2` с названием `form`, потом после загрузки (или в другом, нужном вам, месте) показываете эту форму и получается что по нажатию кнопки в первой форме, фон изменится во второй.